# New modal onpress marker in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to understand how modal it works in React Native

What I want, it's when I click on marker, it display me the different information of specific marker (title, description, name).

What I have:

```
export default class MapsScreen extends React.Component {
state = { reports: [] }

componentDidMount() {
    // call api
}

mapMarkers = () => {
    return this.state.reports.map((report) => <Marker
    key={report.key}
    title={report.name}
    coordinate={{ latitude: report.latitude, longitude: report.longitude }}
    title={report.name}
    description={report.description}
    onPress={this._onMarkerPress.bind(this, this.state.reports.filter(r => r.key === report.key ))}

    >
    </Marker >)
}

render() {
    return (
        <MapView
        style={{ ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject }}
        initialRegion={{
            latitude: 52.0,
            longitude: -0.98,
            latitudeDelta: 10,
            longitudeDelta: 5
        }} >
        {this.mapMarkers()}
        
        </MapView>
        );
    }

    _onMarkerPress (markerData) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(markerData));
    }
}
```

How can I start for do What I want ?

Thanks for your help :)